# OpenCV wont object detect with MSS screen capture

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, python-mss

I'm new to Python and want to learn it bit by bit, so I decided to write a simple program that would, in real time, capture my screen and do object detection. Through a lot of googling and reading, I was able to make this script, however, no matter what I do, it won't do object detection (m1.png).

Can you please assist me with the reason why it is like this?

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy


#template and dimensions
template = cv2.imread("m2.png")
template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
template_w, template_h = template_gray.shape[::-1]

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 523, "left": 247, "width": 875, "height": 679}

    while True:
        last_time = time.time()
        
        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(
            image = img_gray,
            templ = template_gray, 
            method= cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
        )

        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

        #threshold
        if max_val >= 0.5:

            img = cv2.rectangle(
                img = img,
                pt1 = max_loc,
                pt2 = (
                    max_loc[0] + template_w, # = pt2 x 
                    max_loc[1] + template_h # = pt2 y
                ),
                color = (0,255,0),
                thickness = 3 #fill the rectangle
            )



        print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

I spent three days trying to figure it out, and the only similar code that works but with a poor frame rate is this one:

```
#imports
from re import template
import cv2
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

#No cooldown time
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0

#template and dimensions
template = cv2.imread("b1.png")
template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
template_w, template_h = template_gray.shape[::-1]

# game window dimensions
x, y, w, h = 523, 247, 875, 679

#wait
sleep(3)

#main

while True:

    #screenshot = img
    pyautogui.screenshot("image.png", (x, y, w, h))
    image = cv2.imread("image.png")

    while True:

        image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

        result = cv2.matchTemplate(
            image = image_gray,
            templ = template_gray,
            method = cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
        )

        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

        #threshold
        if max_val >= 0.1:
            #pyautogui.click(
            #    x = max_loc[0] + x, #screen x
            #    y = max_loc[1] + y  #screen y
            #)

            image = cv2.rectangle(
                img = image,
                pt1 = max_loc,
                pt2 = (
                    max_loc[0] + template_w, # = pt2 x 
                    max_loc[1] + template_h # = pt2 y
                ),
                color = (0,0,255),
                thickness = -1 #fill the rectangle
            )
        
        else:
            break
```

The structure looks similar the only difference in this template is that it uses pyautogui with OpenCV, whereas I'm trying to use mss. So does that mean that the issue in the code is that there's no physical location of the screen capture due? If so, does that mean it's impossible to make an object detection with mss?? You would make my day if you could disclose this mystery with the code!!

UPD: I was able to solve this, honey! So the issue was that firstly I misspelled the .png file, and to see it detecting an object, place the cv2.imshow after the if statement. Although it works, it's not perfect, so I'm trying to implement the usage of `cv2.Canny()` but now I don't get any output, so here I'm rising a question of whether there should be a different approach when Canny is used:

```
import time
import Options.settings as set
import time
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

x = 0

offset = set.offset
create_logs = set.create_logs

#template and dimensions
template = cv2.imread("m2.png")
template_gray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
template_canny = cv2.Canny(template_gray, 79, 100)
template_w, template_h = template_canny.shape[::-1]

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 523, "left": 1600, "width": 230, "height": 359}

    while True:
        last_time = time.time()
        
        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
        img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 100, 115)

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(
            image = img_canny,
            templ = template_canny, 
            method= cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED
        )

        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

        #threshold
        if max_val >= 0.6:
            x = x + 1
            print(f'{x} is detected')
        
            img = cv2.rectangle(
                img = img,
                pt1 = max_loc,
                pt2 = (
                    max_loc[0] + template_w, # = pt2 x 
                    max_loc[1] + template_h # = pt2 y
                ),
                color = (0,255,0),
                thickness = 3 #fill the rectangle
            )
        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow("Normal", img)



        #print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

UPD 2:
As @fmw42 suggested, I tried different OpenCV methods, but whether I try them, they constantly react if there's an object in the screen capture field no matter how I change the `if max_vol >= ...`

Please find attached
m2.png = https://ibb.co/Xb5tCPZ
Example of what the screen capture look like = https://ibb.co/Xb5tCPZ

Comment: Are you sure you are actually capturing the screen? Do you get any error messages? If so, what are they are and where do they occur. Try TM_CORR_NORMED.

Comment: @fmw42 No, there was only one error due to misspelling the .png name, but I solved it. Also, by moving the cv2.imshow after the if statement, I managed to make it work, although the accuracy in some areas is lacking, so I'm trying to make it work with the cv2. Canny, but even though the input and output look almost 100% identical, it doesn't want to detect it

Comment: I don't recommend TM_COEFF_NORMED. USE TM_CORR_NORMED or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED or just TM_SQDIFF

Comment: @fmw42 is it more efficient and accurate? Because in some areas the detection is unstable so I switched to ```cv2.Canny``` to lessen external variables that could prevent it from accurate detection, but unfortunately, it stopped complete work now ;;;
You can find it above^^

Comment: @fmw42 Also did you meant TM_CCORR_NORMED ? Because I can't find TM_CORR_NORMED

Comment: it also looks like TM_CCORR_NORMED can't work with this program because it non stops activating if statement as if the object is in the area of capture but in reality, there's nothing. It also makes imshow grey...

Comment: I do not understand your comment. I use TM_CORR_NORMED all the time with no issues.

Comment: @fmw42 Could you please try to run the code with the samples that I provided in my case, if I try any other methods, it will work in a way as if there's an object detected on the screen capture even though there isn't any. Changing ```if max_vol >= ...``` value doesn't work

Comment: I do not use pyautogui. Post your image and template and I can try to use the rest of your code.

Comment: @fmw42 code is under UPD and the image that I used is in the UPD2 with sample image for screen capture

Comment: Which code do you want me to try?  Your two images are the same size?  Is that what you are using? What are you trying to achieve?  Can you not just do image subtraction and measure how much difference there is? As I said before, rather than getting all values above a threshold, find just the max value and its location.  See my examples that I posted links in my comments.

Answer (score 0):

alright, somehow, I get the idea behind the issue,
I had to move after the if function and now it's working^^

```
# Display the picture
cv2.imshow("Normal", img)
```